# How do I plumb an outside line to a roof deck faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, outdoor, pex, copper-tubing

I want to get water from the first floor up along the outside of the wall (with a parapet and projecting coping) to the second floor.

[image]

I got this working as follows:  1st floor hose bibb -> 4:1 hose adapter -> Garden hose-mpt adapter->mpt-sharkbite 90 degree elbow -> 14 foot run of 1/2" PEX that goes through a 45 degree curve (now vertical), and then goes in rounded manner over the parapet wall (supported only at the top, and over to a Sharkbite->MPT(Female) ->hose bibb attached to the deck railing.

Works fine, but PEX degrades in sunlight, so this isn't a long-term solution.  I'm concerned that the copper is heavier than the PEX and will put a lot of weight on the 4-1 hose adapter, and since the pipe is 6+ inches off the wall (thanks to the parapet), it isn't easy to support it.

What can I replace this with -- soft copper coil?  Hard pipe with sharkbite fittings?  PVC (???)

How do I support this from the top (I'd rather not drill holes in my wall)?

Comment: Why have all those adapters? Cut the hose bib off start from the 1/2" pipe

Comment: The hose bibb goes to the 4-1 adapter that feeds a garden hose and a garden timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... since nobody responded.

I used 2 10' straight pipes as well as a 10' of soft copper tubing, and a bunch of couplers and 45 degree elbows.  I used copper clips and masonry screws to attach the pipe to the wall and to the upper hanger, and used sweated joints througout.  Was much slower than using PEX!

Comment: Hope you're in a non-freezing climate, or that you've planned a way to completely drain those pipes over the winter months, or both...

Comment: There's a hose connector to the 4:1 hose adapter, and it unscrews... The 4-1 hose adapter also has an empty port, so it tends to drain out if you turn off the water and open the empty port.

Comment: @keshlam Oops. thought I'd opened the valve when I closed it. Blew 3 holes in the copper pipe.  Now is running with dishwasher connector on the garden hose to a MNPT fitting on the copper pipe.